# Defining an Object with Multilevel inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

Let's assume, we need create a map which **must** offer concurrency and therefore, we decided to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`. However, The `ConcurrentHashMap` implements `ConcurrentMap`, and `ConcurrentMap` implements `Map` interface (Multilevel inheritance). Since referring to objects by their interfaces is the best practice in Java, which is the best way to define the object in this situation? And please share the reason too.

```
ConcurrentMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
```

or

```
Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
```

Comment: second one is just fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your code is aware of concurrency and needs to call concurrent methods like putIfAbsent, the only choice is ConcurrentMap. If you will only use put/remove/get, it's better to choose Map.

Answer (score 2):

See you do realize, that ConcurrentMap extends Map interface, so it has all the methods which Map has, and it has also some other methods of its own. Now if you want to use some method which is defined in ConcurrentMap interface and not Map interface, then you definitely will need something like this.

```
ConcurrentMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
```

But suppose, you want to perform only basic operations which are present in Map interface as well, so now both the declarations are valid. Now the question comes, which declaration is most suited. Let us see it with one example.

Let us assume you have a method `returnMap()`. It checks a variable `isSynchronizationRequired`. If this variable is true, then return ConcurrentHashMap, otherwise return HashMap. The code goes something like this.

```
 public Map returnMap(){
    Map map;
    if(isSynchroniztionRequired){
      map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    }else{
      map = new HashMap();
    }
    return map;
  }
```

Clearly declaring an instance of Map interface and assigning it different objects based on conditions, is more suited here.

Answer (score 0):

> Since referring to objects by their interfaces is the best practice in
>   Java, which is the best way to define the object in this situation?
>   And please share the reason too.
>
> ConcurrentMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap(); or
>
> Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap();

The contract for `Map` is defined in the Java Collections Framework.  This contract is extended by *and is refined by* the `ConcurrentMap` interface in the Java concurrency package.

The answer as to which type to use, therefore, depends mainly on which contract is most important for the work you're trying to do.

- If your code is performing work that it is covered by the contract in the Java Collections Framework and doesn't require the special facilities defined in the extended interface, then you'll be able to interoperate with more code by using the `Map` interface as your type.
- If your code specifically requires features that are defined by the refined contract of the `ConcurrentMap` interface (such as the atomic `putIfAbsent()` method), then it is important to use that type in order to have access to those features.  Your code will be less interoperable with code written for the Java Collections Framework, but that's usually an acceptable tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParentClass parent = new BaseClass()
```

This type of assignment is generally used when you have multiple classes extending from ParentClass and based on some condition, an object of one of the class will be created and assigned reference of the parent class.